# Binding adapter used to display images from URL using Picasso

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, picasso, android-databinding

I have a project in Github : https://github.com/AliRezaeiii/News-Cache

It includes following Binding adapter :

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
fun bindImage(cardView: CardView, url: String) {

    val imageView: ImageView = cardView.findViewById(R.id.article_poster)
    Picasso.with(cardView.context).load(url).into(
        imageView,
        PicassoPalette.with(url, imageView)
            .use(PicassoPalette.Profile.VIBRANT)
            .intoBackground(cardView.findViewById(R.id.article_background), PicassoPalette.Swatch.RGB)
            .intoTextColor(cardView.findViewById(R.id.article_name), PicassoPalette.Swatch.BODY_TEXT_COLOR)
    )
}
```

And this is my NewsAdapter :

```
class NewsAdapter : ListAdapter<Article, NewsAdapter.NewsViewHolder>(DiffCallback) {

    /**
     * Called when RecyclerView needs a new {@link ViewHolder} of the given type to represent
     * an item.
     */
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = NewsViewHolder.from(parent)

    /**
     * Called by RecyclerView to display the data at the specified position. This method should
     * update the contents of the {@link ViewHolder#itemView} to reflect the item at the given
     * position.
     */
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NewsViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position))
    }

    /**
     * ViewHolder for News items. All work is done by data binding.
     */
    class NewsViewHolder(val binding: NewsItemBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(news: Article) {
            with(binding) {
                article = news
                executePendingBindings()
            }
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): NewsViewHolder {
                val binding = NewsItemBinding.inflate(
                    parent.context.layoutInflater,
                    parent,
                    false
                )
                return NewsViewHolder(binding)
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Allows the RecyclerView to determine which items have changed when the [List] of [Article]
     * has been updated.
     */
    companion object DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Article>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
            return oldItem === newItem
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
            return oldItem.url == newItem.url
        }
    }
}
```

This is my LiveData that get observed in Fragment :

```
viewModel.news.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<List<Article>> { articles ->
            articles?.apply {
                viewModelAdapter?.submitList(articles)
            }
        })
```

And here is how I setup recyclerView adapter :

```
viewModelAdapter = NewsAdapter()

        with(binding) {
            recyclerView.apply {
                addItemDecoration(MarginDecoration(context))
                setHasFixedSize(true)
                adapter = viewModelAdapter
            }
        }
```

For some reason when I scroll the recyclerView to end and com back to beginning it starts to load the images again. I expect it to be cached. What is my mistake?

Comment: I think you've not added the cache policy off picasso

Comment: Could you please show me how can I add cache policy?

Answer (score 0):

Modify it with

```
//10MB Cache
Picasso picasso =  new Picasso
    .Builder(this)
    .downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(getCacheDir(), 10000000))
    .build();
```

Create this instance when the application is started and use this instance without recreating.

```
picasso.with(cardView.context).load(url).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(
    imageView,
    PicassoPalette.with(url, imageView)
        .use(PicassoPalette.Profile.VIBRANT)
        .intoBackground(cardView.findViewById(R.id.article_background), PicassoPalette.Swatch.RGB)
        .intoTextColor(cardView.findViewById(R.id.article_name), PicassoPalette.Swatch.BODY_TEXT_COLOR)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should specify the caching mechanism as follows:

```
Picasso.with(cardView.context)
.networkPolicy(OFFLINE, NO_CACHE)
.load(url)
.into(view)
```